# Python read .json files from GCS into pandas DF in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, google-cloud-storage, python-asyncio

**TL;DR:** `asyncio` vs `multi-processing` vs `threading` vs. `some other solution` to parallelize for loop that reads files from GCS, then appends this data together into a pandas dataframe, then writes to BigQuery...

I'd like to make parallel a python function that reads hundreds of thousands of small **.json** files from a GCS directory, then converts those **.jsons** into pandas dataframes, and then writes the pandas dataframes to a BigQuery table.

Here is a not-parallel version of the function:

```
import gcsfs
import pandas as pd
from my.helpers import get_gcs_file_list
def load_gcs_to_bq(gcs_directory, bq_table):

    # my own function to get list of filenames from GCS directory
    files = get_gcs_file_list(directory=gcs_directory) # 

    # Create new table
    output_df = pd.DataFrame()
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem() # Google Cloud Storage (GCS) File System (FS)
    counter = 0
    for file in files:

        # read files from GCS
        with fs.open(file, 'r') as f:
            gcs_data = json.loads(f.read())
            data = [gcs_data] if isinstance(gcs_data, dict) else gcs_data
            this_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            output_df = output_df.append(this_df)

        # Write to BigQuery for every 5K rows of data
        counter += 1
        if (counter % 5000 == 0):
            pd.DataFrame.to_gbq(output_df, bq_table, project_id=my_id, if_exists='append')
            output_df = pd.DataFrame() # and reset the dataframe


    # Write remaining rows to BigQuery
    pd.DataFrame.to_gbq(output_df, bq_table, project_id=my_id, if_exists='append')
```

This function is straightforward:

- grab `['gcs_dir/file1.json', 'gcs_dir/file2.json', ...]`, the list of file names in GCS
- loop over each file name, and:

  - read the file from GCS
  - converts the data into a pandas DF
  - appends to a main pandas DF
  - every 5K loops, write to BigQuery (since the appends get much slower as the DF gets larger)

I have to run this function on a few GCS directories each with ~500K files. Due to the bottleneck of reading/writing this many small files, this process will take ~24 hours for a single directory... It would be great if I could make this more parallel to speed things up, as it seems like a task that lends itself to parallelization.

**Edit**: The solutions below are helpful, but I am particularly interested in running in parallel from within the python script. Pandas is handling some data cleaning, and using `bq load` will throw errors. There is [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and this [gcloud-aio-storage](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud-aio-storage/) that both seem potentially useful for this task, maybe as better options than threading or multiprocessing...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can directly use `bq` command give the path to the GCS folder and the table name in bigquery. This will be faster

Comment: what `bq` command is this that you're referring to?

Comment: I have put an answer so that others who face same problem can look at it

Answer (score 2):

Rather than add parallel processing to your python code, consider invoking your python program multiple times in parallel.  This is a trick that lends itself more easily to a program that takes a list of files on the command line.  So, for the sake of this post, let's consider changing one line in your program:

Your line:

```
# my own function to get list of filenames from GCS directory
files = get_gcs_file_list(directory=gcs_directory) #
```

New line:

```
files = sys.argv[1:]  # ok, import sys, too
```

Now, you can invoke your program this way:

```
PROCESSES=100
get_gcs_file_list.py | xargs -P $PROCESSES your_program
```

`xargs` will now take the file names output by `get_gcs_file_list.py` and invoke `your_program` up to 100 times in parallel, fitting as many file names as it can on each line.  I believe the number of file names is limited to the maximum command size allowed by the shell.  If 100 processes is not enough to process all your files, xargs will invoke `your_program` again (and again) until all file names it reads from stdin are processed.  `xargs` ensures that no more than 100  invocations of `your_program` are running simultaneously. You can vary the number of processes based on the resources available to your host.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for sharing. I currently invoke my program as `tasks` in an Airflow `DAG` that runs daily, and I'm not quite sure how to introduce this pattern into Airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this, you can directly use `bq` command.

> The bq command-line tool is a Python-based command-line tool for BigQuery.

When you use this command, loading takes place in google's network which is very fast than we creating a dataframe and loading to table.

```
    bq load \
    --autodetect \
    --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/my_json_folder/*.json
```

For more information - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table

Comment: I will try this. I am concerned about `type` issues with my data, which can occur as the data is messy, although it seems your shared command has an `--autodetect` flag to handle this?

Comment: `--autodetect` will automatically detect the type and tries to apply the type, else it will throw error