# How to multiprocess iteratively into several numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

Which is the correct way to parallelize this? Essentially, I have a very large 2D array I want to do a linear fit of each row to a separate array of the same length (x), which would be constant for all the rows. The expected result is a 1D array (data_slopes) with the linear fit slopes. This code works but it is very slow:

```
for j in range(img1_data_r.shape[0]):

    y = img1_data_r[j,:]
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x.reshape((-1, 1)),y,1)
    data_slopes[j] = model.coef_[0]
```

I have no previous experience with multiprocessing pool and I have been trying unsuccessfully

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiprocess iteratively"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Instead of iterating over the ranges, what I would recommend is that you make a function that takes in a 2D array and returns your expected `LinearRegression` output. Then you can create a list that has all the 2D arrays you need to iterate over (iterator) -

```
#Function that works on a single object
def fn(x):
    out = x**3 #your code here
    return out

iterator = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  #list of objects that you need to run your function on

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)  #Number of cores you want to utilize
results = [pool.apply_async(fn, args=(x,)) for x in iterator] #maps the iterator and the function to each core asynchronously
output = [p.get() for p in results]   #collects and returns the results as a list of outputs.
output
```

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```

`pool.apply_async` should be superfast along with the list comprehensions since it asynchronously passes the operations to the cores without waiting for all cores to finish their operations before passing the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in the domain of the data that needs to processed, you can use `xargs` to run your program in parallel.  `xargs` allows you to execute a program in parallel, passing in different parameters read from stdin.  I've used it successfully to make bash shells work in parallel.

See if this question helps you:  [Python read .json files from GCS into pandas DF in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045305/python-read-json-files-from-gcs-into-pandas-df-in-parallel/63045749#63045749)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use `multiprocessing` to operate on rows of a 2d numpy array and a constant vector.

In this example, the same vector `b` (equivalent to your `x`) is dot-producted with each of the rows of the `a` array.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def dot_product(row, vec):
    return (row * vec).sum()

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12]])

b = np.array([10, 11, 12])

p = Pool(3)  # max number of simultaneous processes

print(p.starmap(dot_product, ((row, b) for row in a)))
```

Note that you can only pass picklable objects to a `multiprocessing.Pool`.  Although numpy arrays are picklable, and a function (such as `dot_product` here) is, instance methods are not. So you could not use your model (`LinearRegression()`) as first argument to `Pool.map` (or `Pool.starmap`).  Instead, you would have to instantiate `LinearRegression` separately inside the function for each process.

Putting this together for you (although obviously I don't have enough information to test this), you would get something like this:

```
def get_data_slope(row, x):
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x.reshape((-1, 1)), row, 1)
    return model.coef_[0]

p = Pool(3)

data_slopes[:] = p.starmap(get_data_slope, ((row, x) for row in img1_data_r))
```